# cannot search value in dataframe althought the value exists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame with location data. I know a value for a certain location exists and I even know its index location. When I search using index location the values is shown correctly but if I search using a combination of other columns(lat and lon), the value does not show.
I am attaching the screenshot below.
[image]

Here I know lat 31.92 and lon 76.66 are at index 2656536. When I subset using lat and lon, the result is empty. The result should have been as shown in the figure.

PS this is only happening only for some values(10%) not all

Comment: although the file showed value as 76.66 the original values were 76.65999999 which caused the problem. Round off to two digits solved the problem.df=df.round({"lat":2, "lon":2})

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is with precision of floats, so we need to use [`numpy.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html):

```
df[(np.isclose(df.lat, 31.92)) & (np.isclose(df.lon, 76.66))]
```

Comment: @jezisrael you are on a roll. take a bow. :)